# Rspec: undefined method `new' error in ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I know this has to be something stupid, but I keep getting the following error in one of my examples:

```
undefined method `new' for #<Class:0x211d274>
```

I have created a simple example to show the error:

```
describe LateCharge do
  before :each do
    @membership = Membership.new
    @location = mock_model(Location, :late_payment_rate => 10)
  end

  it "should initialize" do
    LateCharge.respond_to?('new').should == true
    @charge = LateCharge.new(@membership, @location)
  end
end
```

The strange part is, when I run the example by itself, it passes. When I run it with all my examples, it fails with the following error:

```
NoMethodError in 'LateCharge should initialize'
undefined method `new' for #<Class:0x211d274>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1964:in `method_missing_without_paginate' 
/Users/l33/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mislav-will_paginate-2.3.11/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:170:in `method_missing' 
./spec/models/late_charge_spec.rb:15:
```

It is failing on the line: @charge = LateCharge.new(@membership, @location)

I do not have any problems instantiating the LateCharge object at run time or from the console.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the following information is key to your issue:

```
will_paginate/finder.rb:170:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Lee - not sure if you're still having this problem, but I had the exact same thing and it's because another spec I had was unstubbing the function.